# Is it possible to have a ListLogPlot of a 1-variable and a 2-variable function in the same plot?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have two functions, a one-variable and a two-variable function
$$ f(n)=\pi ^2 n^2 ,\quad  g(n,m)=\cos m+\pi ^2 n^2 $$
for $n=1,2,3,...10$ and $m\in[0,2\pi]$.

Then, is it possible to have a Plot of these two functions in the logarithmic scale and in the same plot?
More precisely, I need something like merging these two plots in the same plot (to compare their numerical values) in the logarithmic scale.   `DiscretePlot3D[ n^2 π^2 + Cos[m], {m, 0, 2π, π/10}, {n, 1, 10, 1}]`  and  `DiscretePlot[n^2 π^2, {n, 1, 10}]` . Is it possible?

```
f[n_] := n^2 \[Pi]^2;
g[n_, m_] := n^2 \[Pi]^2 + Cos[m];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
ClearAll[g, f]
g[n_, m_] := n^2 π^2 + Cos[m]
f[n_, m_] := ConditionalExpression[n^2 π^2 + Cos[m], Mod[m, Pi/2] == 0]

DiscretePlot3D[{Log[g[n, m]], Log[f[n, m]]}, {m, 0, 2 π, π/10}, {n, 1, 10, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red},
  PlotLegends -> {HoldForm @ Log[n^2 π^2 + Cos[m]], HoldForm @ Log[n^2 π^2]}]
```

[image]

Define `f` as

```
f[n_, m_] := ConditionalExpression[n^2 π^2 + Cos[m], m == Pi/2]
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this?

```
Show[{ListPointPlot3D[
Table[{n, m, Log[ g[n, m] ] }, {n, 1, 10}, {m,Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 20]}],
AxesLabel -> {n, m, None},ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
, ParametricPlot3D [Table[{n, m, Log[f[n]]}, {n, 1, 10}], {m, 0, 2 Pi}, 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes, something like this.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

The new question maybe this

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[Log[n^2 π^2 + Cos[m]], {m, 0, 2 π, π/10}, {n, 1, 
   10, 1}]]
```

**Original**

```
f[n_] := n^2 π^2;
g[n_, m_] := n^2 π^2 + Cos[m];
figa = ListPlot[Table[f[n], {n, 10}], ScalingFunctions -> "Log"];
(* figc = ListLogPlot[Table[f[n], {n, 10}]]; *)
figb = Plot[Table[g[n, m], {n, 1, 10}] // Evaluate, {m, 0, 2 π}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> "Log", PlotRange -> All];
Show[figb, figa]
```

Or

```
f[n_] := n^2 π^2;
g[n_, m_] := n^2 π^2 + Cos[m];
figc = ListLogPlot[Table[f[n], {n, 10}]];
figd = Plot[
   Table[Log@g[n, m], {n, 1, 10}] // Evaluate, {m, 0, 2 π}, 
   PlotRange -> All];
Show[figc, figd]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately, ScalingFunctions -> "Log" in figb does not work in the version I use.

Comment: @charmin   The second approach work or not?

Comment: Thanks, yes, it works. But as I edited in the post, wanted to know can we plot the 2-variable function as a surface and the 1-variable function as discrete points in the same plot? In your approach 2-variable function is shown as lines and it ends at $n=2\pi$.

Comment: @charmin What means "discrete points f[n]"  in the n,m-space?

Comment: @cvgmt   I need something like merging these two plots in the same plot in the logarithmic scale.  ```  DiscretePlot3D[
 n^2 π^2 + Cos[m], {m, 0, 2π, π/10}, {n, 1, 10, 1}] ```  and  ``` DiscretePlot[n^2 π^2, {n, 1, 10}]  ```. Is it possible?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  I need something like merging these two plots in the same plot (to compare their numerical values) in the logarithmic scale.  ```  DiscretePlot3D[
 n^2 π^2 + Cos[m], {m, 0, 2π, π/10}, {n, 1, 10, 1}] ```  and  ``` DiscretePlot[n^2 π^2, {n, 1, 10}]  ```. Is it possible?